# Python Windows Enum Installed Fonts

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, fonts, ctypes

I am trying to get a list of installed fonts on Windows machines so that I can then install missing ones. I'm on Py3.*, Windows 7.

Looking through the [win API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-enumfontfamiliesexw) documentation I know that I need to use `EnumFontFamiliesExW` however I'm not sure what the correct syntax is with ctypes in python... I'm totally new to the ctypes module, and don't know a lot about C. The python documentation for ctypes is extremely hard for me to grasp, so sorry if I'm not able to find this answer there (I did indeed look).

I got as far as the following:

```
gdi32 = ctypes.WinDLL('gdi32')
print(gdi32.EnumFontFamiliesExW())
```

Which of course throws an error because I am not specifying any arguments. So how do I pass the correct arguments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

pywin32 extension provides an easier option. Use `import win32gui`, `import win32api`, ...

```
import win32gui

def callback(font, tm, fonttype, names):
    names.append(font.lfFaceName)
    return True

font_names = []
hdc = win32gui.GetDC(None)
win32gui.EnumFontFamilies(hdc, None, callback, font_names)
print("\n".join(font_names))
win32gui.ReleaseDC(hdc, None)
```

---

With `ctype` you have to know C and WinAPI. Here is an example to do this in `ctype`, base on https://github.com/wwwtyro/AegisLuna/blob/master/pyglet/font/win32query.py

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

class LOGFONT(ctypes.Structure): _fields_ = [
    ('lfHeight', wintypes.LONG),
    ('lfWidth', wintypes.LONG),
    ('lfEscapement', wintypes.LONG),
    ('lfOrientation', wintypes.LONG),
    ('lfWeight', wintypes.LONG),
    ('lfItalic', wintypes.BYTE),
    ('lfUnderline', wintypes.BYTE),
    ('lfStrikeOut', wintypes.BYTE),
    ('lfCharSet', wintypes.BYTE),
    ('lfOutPrecision', wintypes.BYTE),
    ('lfClipPrecision', wintypes.BYTE),
    ('lfQuality', wintypes.BYTE),
    ('lfPitchAndFamily', wintypes.BYTE),
    ('lfFaceName', ctypes.c_wchar*32)]

#we are not interested in NEWTEXTMETRIC parameter in FONTENUMPROC, use LPVOID instead
FONTENUMPROC = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, 
    ctypes.POINTER(LOGFONT), wintypes.LPVOID, wintypes.DWORD, wintypes.LPARAM)

fontlist = []
def font_enum(logfont, textmetricex, fonttype, param):
    str = logfont.contents.lfFaceName;
    if (any(str in s for s in fontlist) == False):
        fontlist.append(str)
    return True

hdc = ctypes.windll.user32.GetDC(None)
ctypes.windll.gdi32.EnumFontFamiliesExW(hdc, None, FONTENUMPROC(font_enum), 0, 0)  
ctypes.windll.user32.ReleaseDC(None, hdc)
print("\n".join(fontlist))
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for all that! That is a LOT more complex than I ever expected... Trying to import win32gui throws an error on py3, so I guess that is no longer a standard module? Cypes worked fine though, but it would have taken me ages to figure that all out! Is there a way to get a list of font files instead of the system font names? That would make it easier for me to compare.

Comment: You can get windows font directory (usually c:\windows\font, but not always) then list all the files in that directory. The file names could be anything. It's better to try to use `EnumFontFamiliesEx` - pywin32 should be available in version 3, it's an additional extension.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Hey sorry for disturbing you but I cant figure how to get the filenames properly.